# How to visualize time series with plotly?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, time-series, plotly

I have a data set that contains two variables: `clicks` *(object)* and `session_time` *(datetime64[ns])*.

I am trying to plot a time series by using plotly. But the output looks pretty weird and I could not find the reason.

Here is the code that I am trying to plot it:

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as numpy

trace = go.Scatter(x=list(df.session_time),
                   y=list(df.clicks), line=dict(color='red'))

dat = [trace]
layout = dict(
    title='Clicks on books',
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(step='all')
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible = True
        ),
        type='date'
    )
)

fig = dict(data=dat, layout=layout)
pyo.iplot(fig)
```

And here the output is: 
[image]

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Can you share more about your data? How are you importing it?

Comment: May I ask you how I can share the sample of data? I've imported the data like this: df = pd.read_csv('clicks.csv') @lincolnck

Comment: After you import the data with pandas, what are the data types for `clicks` and `session_time`? Are they `class 'pandas.core.series.Series'`

Comment: By sorting your time data, I got it to work. Try adding this after converting to datetime. `df.sort_values(by=['session_time'], inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`go.Scatter` is plotting your data as a scatterplot, and since your datetime data is out of order, it's plotting it out of order.
After converting your `session_time` column to datetime, sorting it by

`df.sort_values(by=['session_time'], inplace=True)`

will resolve your issue. This may not be the most elegant solution, but it works.

[image: Sorted Datetime]